# PHP Codeigniter site_url produce HTML link error

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

in my view, i try to print URL to my controller, below the code :

```
<p id="demo">
<a href="<?php echo site_url('HT');?>"> Goto Controller </a>
</p>
```

However those code provide HTML link error like this :

```
<a href="http://::1/cidLab/index.php/HT"> Goto Controller </a>
```

The link should be go to **`http://localhost/cidLab/index.php/HT`** but why must **`http://::1/`** ?

I've try to use base_url, but still face same Error...

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 loopback address, just as `127.0.0.1` is the IPv4 loopback address. It's just the IP representation of localhost and should still work. I wouldn't bother too much about how the URL looks on your local development environment as long as it works.

Comment: @Oldskool if i paste the ipv6 url to browser then it will go to google....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about Codeigniter changed it's config structure. After version 3.0.3, you must configure

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

in config.php file at application/config folder.

This change is about security rules. They says, empty base_url may be security hole.

Base url must be your site url. If you test your application in local, you may set this url as localhost

Answer (score 2):

Please add your base url here

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project';
```

Comment: Need to be with trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('/cidLab/index.php/HT');?>"
```